# Python script to compare 2 csv files , and find difference on the basis of primary key

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, etl

Python script to compare 2 csv files , and find difference on the basis of primary key ie we need to find the primary key from two files and validate corresponding data .

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is the exact file extension used here? Can you export to tsv or csv instead of excel?

Comment: The file extension is xlsx. The header is given below -

Comment: i have 2 txt files which has data separated by comma. Now I want to compare these two flat files and get the result preferably in csv so that I can see the difference.the two txt flat file is having header at the beginning.

Comment: can anyone help me on this and let me find the difference.